# TCPDF: PDF page size too big

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

I've set the 'PDF_PAGE_FORMAT' to A4, but every time I generate the PDF it's about 10 cm wider and 6 cm too big in height.
This issue also persists when I try to enter custom values, it creates a page that's bigger than I want it to be.

I have no idea where to look. I am trying to create an a4 sized pdf with an full a4 sized image on it, that's all. This is what I have so far.

```
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Ernst Jacobs');
$pdf->SetTitle('TechniekMuseum HEIM Certificate');

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set image scale factor
//$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setImageScale(1.53);

// set JPEG quality
$pdf->setJPEGQuality(100);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Image('images/cert_rd_em.jpg');


// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'tcpdf/examples/saves/certificate.pdf', 'I');
```